# Book with time machine device size of a phone and limited number of operations

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

In 2002, I read a book about a preteen or teen who somehow found a kind of time machine device.

It was just kind of the size of a phone, and in the book I believe it was described as something like a circuit board.

I think it had a number on it that would go down each time he would use it. Usually every time he would use it he would go back in time  and do something a different way that he thought worked out better or he would do stuff purposely then quickly go back in time.

At the end around the last times he can use the machine, he uses it to save a friend who is a girl. So she dies but his last time he can use the machine is spent on her and it makes this huge deal about it.

Either that or I believe it breaks somehow in the process.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What language was it in? What was the cover like? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: The plot you described is extremely similar to the animated movie *The Girl who Leapt Through Time*, based on a 1966 Japanese novel. But the genders are reversed, and neither the movie nor an English translation of the novel existed in 2002.

Comment: Also, you read it in 2002, which makes a great start, but do you have any idea if it was new then or if it might have been much older (either from the circumstances you read it, or in-text indicators like how computers were described, if at all)?

Comment: The Power of Un by Nancy Etchemendy?